# Pressing submit button in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, ui-automation, ui-testing

I am developing C# desktop program to do some automatic posting

1. I am opening the web page (with form) in C# webbrowser control
2. Once it opens the page, I am filling form field with data ( Using C# code). So no manual interaction

My question is: How do I automatically send data to the server (in other word how do I press submit button using C# code)?

Comment: If this is for web UI testing then you should specify that otherwise I can see you getting bombarded with "You should use HttpWebRequest".

Comment: Yes this is for the UI testing work for my php applications

Answer (score 1):

Basically using the same code to locate and populate the fields, you can traverse the DOM to find the submit button and send it a click via invoke.

```
theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection) {
        if (curElement.GetAttribute("id").Equals("login_button")) {
            curElement.InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: Just curious - did you try stepping through to make sure it was getting the element? I've written a few of these programs and had to implement a few workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WatiN](http://watin.org/) . But I personally would use `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` to get/post data from/to the server

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I am looking for some working example with C# web browser control

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit a form you check this,

```cs
// get the document
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)webBrowser1.Document);

// set a variable
((mshtml.IHTMLElement)doc.all.item("q")).setAttribute("value", "my input...");

// click a button
((mshtml.HTMLInputElement)doc.all.item("btnI")).click();
```

The namespace `mshtml` is located in the `Microsoft.mshtml` Assembly.

Just add a reference to `Microsoft.mshtml`.